# Редактирование файла php

Tags: php

Имеется файл с настройками, хочется его редактировать. Не разу с таким не сталкивался. Есть ли варианты изменять значение в переменной не переписывая весь файл? пример содержания:

```
$test['test'] = "1"; 
$test['test2'] = "555";
```

Comment: а чего минусуют? вполне резонный вопрос когда работать надо уже с тем, что есть...

Comment: - тыкнуть легко, а решить такую задачу не все могут...

Answer (score 3):

> Есть ли варианты изменять значение в переменной не переписывая весь файл?

Нет.

Answer (score 3):

Перезаписывать весь файл вам всё равно придётся. Диски не умеют операцию "вставить пару байт между вот этими двумя байтами". Диски умеют "замени полностью содержимое LBA N на вот это".
И если новые данные меньше старых - то их ещё в теории можно добить какими-нибудь пробелами. А вот если больше - только перезаписывать весь последующий файл.

В общем, мороки очень много, профита никакого. Диску всё равно, записать 2 байта или 512 - это всё равно одна операция записи цельного блока. А современные и кусками по 4кб пишут. Это я ещё ОС и файловые системы не рассматриваю.

Поэтому берите `var_export` и `file_put_contents` - просто, компактно и понятно.

Comment: наверное я неправильно выразил смысл слова "перезапись"

Answer (score 0):

Что бы хранить настройки как правило используют фалы с расширениям json или xml.
На данный момент предпочитают json больше.

Comment: можно хранить и в БД. Тут задача стала на том что уже есть. А есть файл php и в нем такая дрянь :(

Comment: @wwwplaton, у вас обычный текстовый файл?

Comment: нет settings.php

Comment: О таком в первый раз слышу. Много там храниться настроек?

Comment: прилично. Хотя насколько я помню даже как то в joomla видел подобный файл настроек. Что тут такого?

Comment: @Deno в yii например такие конфиги по дефолту

Comment: @wwwplaton все что пришло на ум, это переписать ваш фал конфигурация. Перенести все значения в json потом  что бы settings.php получал данные с json а вы затем сможете редактировать json

Comment: @Deno в таком случае мне проще создать "шаблон файла с настройками" подставлять новые данные в него и сохранять. Быстро и просто. Но я все же думал что кто то подскажет способ интереснее. А вместо этого натыкали - :(